# How do we infer this learning curve

Tags: deep-learning

I am witnessing following learning curve for my model. Does it look like a perfect theoretical training?

My model is decently complex ( has transformers in it ) and weights amount to about 600 MB size.

The data volume is also decent (10k point clouds post augmentation )

Here is the learning curve :
[image]

updated curve:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you add another y-axis for the F1 score?

Comment: yes, have removed it for now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The validation and training loss curves (blue and orange) look quite OK to me, they start high and gradually decrease until they are close to flat curves. It is a bit unclear what the green curve represents, the label says it's the F1 score on the validation set but the y axis has a label `Loss` and the y-ticks are inconsistent with the range of values for an F1 score.

Comment: Green curve represents F1 score ( based on precision and recall ) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score. F1 score is scaled by factor of 10k to match scales on the plot. The val scores are evaluated based on both loss metric and F1 scores.

Comment: I'd put the F1 score on a separate axis; doesn't feel natural to have it scaled by some large factor to have it match some other scale

Comment: Stefan, thanks for the suggestion. I have removed the F-score from this chart. Have updated the learning curve with only losses and in the meantime epochs have progressed as well. How does it look to you now, please find updated curve .

Comment: Looks better. Noticed that on the second curve you train for longer, and that the training error further decreases while the validation stays more or less the same. That means your model is starting to overfit, so I'd stop training somewhere around the 35-40th epoch, because there the validation error is closest to the training (good sign of generalisation).

Comment: Right. So I stopped the training. Took the checkpoint from epoch 50. Added some attention dropouts and MLP dropouts and resumed the training. Lets see how it goes :)